# From past 3 days, getting a lot of Spam Traffic from US, How to Block?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, plesk

Before I go ahead let me mention couple of things,

I'm having a dedicated server with CentOS 7, Plesk Onyx Web Pro Edition with Firewall, Fail2Ban & Modsecurity switched ON and nginx as my main webserver. (Not using Apache)

From past 3 days, all of a sudden there was a spike in traffic and it was showing from USA in Google Analytics. First I was happy but then I noticed there was no increase in server load, there was no increase in revenue and the bounce rate started going up. These were clear signs of an attack or a bot traffic.

I tried searching for a solution and each time I Google I always land up on sites mentioning about ghost spam which I think could be the reason here as the site is under no load and its just GA or maybe I am wrong. Anyway I followed the article and found that there are no spam hostnames at all and the most of traffic from my my own domain itslef as hostname and it's mostly shoing in direct traffic.

Then I installed Wordfence Security plugin but it worked for a day only. Then I setup cloudflare with I'm under attack mode and a firewall filter of known bots, its blocking IPs but there is no change in real time traffic.

As I'm using Plesk so I searched for plesk and there was a thread going for WordPress Toolkit security features but that didn't work either.

Tried a nginx bad bot block article and that didn't work either!

I'm really worried now and I'm not sure that I'll loose rankings or what but this is really harmful for the site.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can block traffic by filtering out IP address by using [cloudflare.com](https://cloudflare.com). Also good thing about this that it's FREE :)

Comment: I am doing that, just blocked the entire US region. Traffic went low but now I am seeing increase in desktop traffic which is the bot traffic. Really worried now.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of the traffic?